# Lamp server restart causing http error 503

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-ec2, lamp

I have restarted my AWS EC2 LAMP stack server with `$ Sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart` after having made some changes to enable .htaccess on httpd.conf.

My server seems to have now crashed and is throwing Http error 503.

I've checked the error log and found this but not sure if it's relevant:

> [Sun Sep 08 03:16:02.048610 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 2599] AH10034: The
>   mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm
>   determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more
>   demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not
>   do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work,
>   but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.

Primarily I'm just trying to get my servers back up and running. Any help at this point is like a glass of water in the Sahara - many many thanks in advance

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266604 Check out this thread